# How to find duplicate rows in a DB2 Table

Tags: sql, duplicates, db2

I was trying to insert data into a large table with 12 columns, but this is the error I got:

> One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by `private` constrains table `private` from having duplicate values for the index key

I want an SQL code that can search through a DB2 table and provide me the duplicate rows in the output so I can delete them. I tried using this code based on what I've seen online so far:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY COL1, COL2, COL3
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

It runs, but is not showing any duplicates in the output.

Not sure if I am doing this properly or if I'm on the right path.

Comment: This query is correct: it will find the existing duplicate Col1/2/3 combinations. What were you doing when you get the error? inserts or updates can cause duplicates (not already existing) can't be found by this query (because the constraint didn't allow them to exist). Also, is the unique index/contraint primary key   defined for Col1,col2,col3 (or a  different set of columns)

Comment: I see what you mean. I was inserting parsed csv data into the table, (which was working up until a certain date). I'm thinking I might be adding information that is a duplicate which would explain why it's not showing up in the table.

Comment: Yes, it can be a single row becoming duplicate when inserted (the other one being in the target table already), or more than one  -already duplicated in the CVS- Generally the CSV data is loaded to a staging table, and the integrity checks are done there before insertin/merging with target.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to identify what constraint you are violating. There should be more information in the error message than you posted that can be of help, but you should be able to find it anyhow. Try the following query:

```
select colname from syscat.keycoluse where constname = 'PRIVATE'
```

If you are violating a UNIQUE index without a constraint, you can look directly in SYSCAT.INDEXCOLUSE:

```
select colname from syscat.indexcoluse where indname = 'PRIVATE' and colorder in ('A','D')
```

SYSCAT.INDEXES is another option:

```
select colnames from syscat.indexes where indname = 'PRIVATE'
```

A drawback with the latter is that included columns (i.e. columns that are not part of the unique definition is also returned)

Once you have the columns involved, you can use those in your group by query. However, you wont find any violations in the target table, since the index/constraint prevented the insertion. You can create a temporary table without the constraint and insert the data there to find out what causes the violation:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE your_table
```

insert the data to tmp and then run the query against tmp to find the culprits